# Jbehave tabular report

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

Is there a way to print in jbehave reports the actual value of a variable?
In the example below, behind the scenes (java steps), jbehave is replacing the `foo` value by `bar` but in the report retrieves `foo`.
Here is the code

```
Given I have something:
| foo |
| foo |
...

Examples:
| foo |
| bar |
```

The report will print:

```
Given I have something:
| foo |
| foo |

...
```

instead of:

```
Given I have something:
| foo |
| bar |

...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the info you give it is pretty hard to find out the problem, but this extract from [documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html) may help:

```
@Given("a stock of <symbol> and a <threshold>") public void aStock(
@Named("symbol") String symbol, @Named("threshold") double threshold) {
    // ... }
```

"Also note that while the characters delimiting the parameter names in the regex pattern are purely conventional - they
only serve the purpose of matching the step method in a readable manner - **the use of the angle brackets is required as it is used to replace the name with the value in the reporting**."